# How to Draw a circle button and make label over it

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-store-apps

I want to make a circle button and label over it but I cant , I tried to make ellipse but I don't know how to make a label over it.
I want to make something exactly like this image [image]
Windows 8 Apps C#

Comment: Have a read of http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5082/Round-Button-in-C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a try on following method:

```
<Grid>
    <Ellipse StrokeThickness="2" Stroke="Black" Width="150">
        <Ellipse.Fill>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Image/someImage.png"/>
        </Ellipse.Fill>
    </Ellipse>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="The Demo Case" Margin="0,60,0,0" Foreground="Green"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a Grid, place the Ellipse followed by the TextBlock in the Grid.

```
<Grid>
   <Ellipse ...  />
   <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
</Grid>
```